# Equivalent of C sharp "public IntPtr pHandle = IntPtr.Zero;" to Delphi "hp: Pointer"

Tags: c#, delphi, pointers, dll

After some research I translated

```
pHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
```

to Delphi

```
var
  pHandle: Pointer;
```

When I break for debug in Delphi I get `$314328`, when I break for debug on C sharp I get an Integer value `134180640`.  Can anyone tell me how to make the correct translation to Delphi?

The Dll function that I am calling in Delphi is:

```
function SAAT_Open(pHandle: Pointer): Boolean; stdcall;
```

The C sharp Function is:

```
[DllImport("RFIDAPI.dll", EntryPoint = "SAAT_Open")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
public static extern bool SAAT_Open(IntPtr pHandle);
```

Comment: Your translation is correct (and it matches the original C declaration of `SAAT_Open()`). The problem is elsewhere, like if you are not initializing `pHandle` correctly.

Comment: I also believe that the pHandle is the problem, not a single clue of how to initiate it correctly. The pHandle gets a value after the call "c# code" 
if (rbnTCP.Checked)
            {
                bInit = RfidApi.SAAT_TCPInit(out pHandle, sReaderIP, iReaderPoint);
            }

Comment: I've explained in my answer how to initialize it. And it's just as your code already does it. With a call to SAAT_TCPInit. From my answer: *If SAAT_TCPInit returns True to indicate success, then the handle value will be valid*.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: assuming his translation of `SAAT_TCPInit()` is accurate and correctly outputting the `pHandle` value to his code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After some research I translated
>
> ```
> pHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
> ```
>
> to Delphi
>
> ```
> var
>   pHandle: Pointer;
> ```
>
> Can anyone tell me how to make the correct translation to Delphi?

C# syntax allows you to initialize a variable in the same statement that you declare the variable:

```
IntPtr Handle = IntPtr.Zero;
```

In Delphi you cannot initialize a local variable as you declare it. So you need to declare it, and then initialize it:

```
var
  Handle: Pointer;
....
Handle := nil;
```

Until you assign to a local variable, of an unmanaged type, its value is undefined.

---

However, if you pass `nil` to `SAAT_Open` then it will fail. The function expects a non null handle. So, initializing to `nil` won't help you. You need to do more. You need to call the function that yields a new handle. That is `SAAT_TCPInit`. The C# code that you show, that initializes the handle to a null value, does so needlessly. Perhaps it does so because the `SAAT_TCPInit` was erroneously translated to use a `ref` parameter for the handle, rather than the correct translation which would be an `out` parameter.

Whilst the above answers the question you asked, it won't help solve your problem. You don't need a null handle, you need an actual handle.

---

> When I break for debug in Delphi I get $314328, when I break for debug on C sharp I get an Integer value 134180640.

Well, after `pHandle = IntPtr.Zero` you absolutely will not see the value `134180640` in C#. You will see the value `0`. There must be some other code that initializes the handle. Presumably a call to `SAAT_TCPInit`. You do need to make that call. I trust that you are doing so.

The handle will not necessarily have the same value on subsequent executions of your program. And need not have the same value in each different program. The handle is actually a dynamically allocated pointer and its address is variable from one run to the next. So it is nothing to worry about if it varies as you have observed. If `SAAT_TCPInit` returns `True` to indicate success, then the handle value will be valid.

Comment: Yes, after the SAAT_TCPInit the Pointer gets the value of 134180640  or some other value in C# but when I do the same with Delphi I get $314328.  Don't really understand the meaning of the Dollar sign.  Plus it does not activate the tag, once I do SAAT_YTagSelect(hp, isenable, $01, sz,  4) where hp is the Pointer

Comment: I explained the `$` prefix in one of your previous questions. I don't understand why you don't accept answers, or respond to questions that we ask you. Perhaps you could review them all, accept the best answers, and along the way learn about the `$` prefix. I think that I answered the question that you asked here. Would you please do me a favour and respond to this comment.

Comment: Ok, sorry, learning how to use this site.  I thought that you would have to accept the answer if it help solve the problem.  I now now that if I accept the answer, it doesn't really mean that the problem was solved.  David, I appreciate your help but believe me I am trying t understand all of this responses.

Comment: You really should go back over your previous questions and accept the best answers. All your recent questions have good answers that should be accepted. The point of this site is to answer the questions that you ask, not to solve your problem. Remember that we cannot see your problem, so you cannot expect us to solve every part of it. I, and everyone else here, would really like to help you but it will only work if you work with us.

Comment: I did understand your response regarding the way c# initializes the  Variable in the same statement and the way of initializing the pHandle pointer in Delphi, the thing is that, once I did the initialization in delphi I still got the same response.

Comment: How are you getting on reviewing your other questions? I'm getting a little fed up of this being a one way process. Can you work with me? See the votes on the comments above. That means my sentiments are echoed by others

Comment: Well I believe that I am not doing so bad.  Maybe I have a language barrier, my first language is Spanish so probably I am not making my self clear.  Yes I can definitely work with you!

Comment: Good. I'll let you get on with dealing with your other questions.

Comment: OK. Well done. Now, I guess you now know what `$` means. Right?

Comment: It is the prefix that indicates a hexadecimal literal

Comment: Great!! We really are getting somewhere. As for this question I think there's nothing more to say. You asked about IntPtr.Zero and that's well covered by answers and comments. And I tried to add more discussion around what I suspect is confusing for you.

Comment: Yes it is.  Thank you so much for your help, I sincerely appreciate if.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET, IntPtr is a representation of a pointer type that is implemented under the hood by an integer, because it can't be an actual .NET pointer (reference), because "real" references have to be managed.  But it can't be a real integer either, or you might do math on it, which is a good way to get memory corruption.  (NOTE: This restriction may or may not exist, depending on which version of C# and/or the CLR you're using.)

But since you can't treat an IntPtr as an integer, the only useful things you can do with one are assign it a value you get from elsewhere, or pass it to some code that expects an IntPtr.  IntPtr.Zero exists to resolve one missing but critically important scenario: the **null** value.  You can't assign `0` to it or test it against `0`, and since it's not a reference, you can't assign or test against **null**.  So they created it as a special constant to represent "IntPtr whose value is null."

If you want to do the equivalent in Delphi, declare the pointer and then initialize it to **nil**.

Comment: IOW, the equivalent of `IntPtr` in Delphi is `Pointer` (or `NativeInt` in recent versions, if you want an integer), and the equivilent of `IntPtr.Zero` in Delphi is `nil` (or 0 if using `NativeInt`).

Comment: You can perform arithmetic on an IntPtr. And at the machine level, pointers and integers are indistinguishable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I just checked, and apparently *some* arithmetic is allowed on `IntPtr`, to my surprise, but a lot of simple operations are forbidden.  Most relevant to this: assigning an integer value to an `IntPtr` is an error, which is why `IntPtr.Zero` exists.

Comment: @Mason All it takes is a cast to assign an int. So you can write `ip := (IntPtr)0;` Assignment from integer is a little needless for pointers. Arithmetic is useful. Only added in .net 4 IIRC.

Comment: @David ...that might explain why I thought it didn't work.  The last time I tried that was under 3.5.

Comment: It's a bit imprecise to say that IntPtr is implemented as an integer type because .net doesn't have unmanaged pointers. .net is implemented in C++ and of course that has pointers. The implementation details aren't really important here.

Comment: @David: The *abstraction* is important here.  The CLR goes to great lengths to pretend that pointers aren't really pointers, and that impacts the way developers are able to use it.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Exactly. Which is why "implemented under the hood by an integer" is not pertinent. Since we are dealing with an abstraction, we don't care about how it is implemented. And indeed since it is an abstraction, the implementation could either an integer or a pointer.